# Inactive UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

Does someone know how the inactive done button in the Contacts App is done?

I would like to implement something similar.

So far I haven't seen any inactive property on UIBarButtonItem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `enabled` property. Of course, you'll need to use your own validation checks on the input controls in your view controller, to determine whether or not to set it enabled.

```
// Assuming the Done button is on the right
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO]; // Disables the button
```

[The `enabled` property is found in `UIBarItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem), the class from which `UIBarButtonItem` inherits, which is why you won't find it in the `UIBarButtonItem` docs.